# using listen-addr with docker daemon

Tags: docker

I am creating docker swarm by deploying docker daemon and running swarm related containers ( old method ). As I am deploying it on AWS cloud so my listening ip address and advertising ip address is different. Currently this feature is in docker swarm only i.e. provide --listen-addr and --advertise-addr.

I wanted to ask if docker daemon have such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

With `dockerd` you can define `--ip=0.0.0.0` which is the default ip interface containers listen on when they start up. The default 0.0.0.0 tends to be correct for users.

You can also pass an option like `-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375` to listen on an IP for client connection instead of the default /var/run/docker.sock socket ([please use TLS if you listen on a public IP](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/)). Dockerd is a server half of a client server application, but by default, it isn't listening on any IP interface.

The advertise addr doesn't apply at all to dockerd since no part of it connects to a key/value store to advertise it's location like Swarm does.

Comment: dockerd may not connect to the key/value store but if you run swarm docker container (in manage or join mode) using this (sudo docker run -d -p 4000:4000 swarm manage -H :4000 --replication --advertise 52.220.79.209:4000 consul://52.220.92.249:8500) command then there is no separate option for --listen-addr and --advertise-addr.

Comment: In the container based swarm scenario, the listen addr is being implied by the port mapping and -H flag to swarm. So in the above, swarm is listening on 0.0.0.0:4000.